# Javascript : is there a way to detect user scrolling, but not scrolling done by code (i.e. scrollLeft etc)?

Tags: javascript, scroll

So. I'm making a page with buttons; clicking the buttons smoothly scrolls the page (actually a container) to anchors located further right. This is done with `container.scrollLeft`.

Now I'm trying to make it so that when the user scrolls manually (scrollbar, mousewheel, arrow keys etc), the automated smooth scrolling instantly stops.

I've tried doing this with `container.addEventListener('scroll',StopScroll,false);` but this fires up for any scroll, even done through code, not just done by the user.
Is there a way to detect only user scrolling ? Or maybe a work-around ?

Also, I'd rather not use Jquery, but I'll switch to it if it's the only way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a feeling that DOM scrolling and event scrolling are managed the same way, and therefore indistinguishable.

However, you might hook into mousedown/keydown and update a variable when a key or mouse button is held, and only perform scrollStop if that variable is set?